# Angular understanding the link function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

i am trying to find out when and how to use the `link` function in angular directives.

Say i have the following directive:

```
    app.directive("lbArticle", function() {
    return {
        restrict : "E",
        templateUrl: 'tpl/directives/information/article.html',
        scope: {
            article: '='
        },
        link: function(scope,element, attr){
            scope.info = attr.article;
        }
    };
});
```

Now passing an object to the `article` attachment of the HTML

```
<lb-article article='{{myObject}}'> </lb-article>
```

When this happens and the directive is rendered it should set a variable called `info` equal to `myObject`

So if `myObject` looked like this:

```
myObject{name: 'Hello', created: '2015-04-04'; }
```

Then the following should display these variables:

**my directive html**

```
   <span class="block text-ellipsis">{{info.name}}</span>
    <small class="text-muted">{{info.created | fromNow}}</small>
```

However this does not work?

As far as i can read for the documentation the `link function` should be used for `DOM`  manipulation and also for setting variables that might be rendered before the actual directive?

Comment: Also, this line `scope.info = attr.article;` has no real use, as you already have `article` in that scope

Comment: Why do you use link in this example? the scope : {...} already makes article available to the template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line `scope.info = attr.article;` is redundant, since you have access to `article` via the two-way binding `=article`. So you can replace all occurrences of `info` with `article` in the template, since that is available in scope. You also need to remove the curly brackets from `<lb-article article='{{myObject}}'> </lb-article>` for two-way binding to work, since you want a reference to the object.

There's a nice, easy to follow [article](http://www.sitepoint.com/practical-guide-angularjs-directives/) on directives, which covers most of these concepts (link/complile functions, two/one-way binding, scopes, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<lb-article article='myObject'> </lb-article>
```

and try now.